# Return value from Word VBA to calling Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

From within MS Excel I have VBA code which runs VBA code within MS Word.  Everything works fine.  I need to return a string value from Word, back into an Excel variable.  Is this possible?

Some irrelevant background... I'm building a list of pdf files within Excel and need to extract values out of each of those pdf files.  Word natively reads pdf, that's why I'm using it.  I have a perfectly working python script that does it but no-one else in the organisation knows python and my manager isn't comfortable having code that only I understand.  Which is fair enough!

Any hint would be appreciated!

Comment: Please [edit] your question with your code.

Comment: You can use clipboard. Copy in Word macro and then paste in Excel from clipboard

Comment: Clipboard!  Of course!  Doh!  Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

Excel:

```
Sub RunWord()

    Dim appWd As Object, res

    Set appWd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

    res = appWd.Run("Tester")

    Debug.Print res

End Sub
```

Word:

```
Public Function Tester()
    Tester = "hi!"
End Function
```